# JMockit: How to mock protected methods?

Tags: java, mocking, jmockit

I'm trying to use JMockit in order to mock a protected method of a class:

```java
public class A {

    protected String say() {
         return "hi";
    }
}

public class B extends A {

     public String cry() {
          return "waaaa " + say();
     }
}
```

I want to mock "say" method in my tests, so that every instance of B, when  it invokes "say", it will get "bye" instead of "hi".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply make a MockUp of A:

```
new MockUp<A> () {
    @Mock protected String say() { return "bye"; }
};
System.out.println(new B().cry()); // prints waaaa bye
```